# jQuery dynamic class add

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

in my website there is a jQuery function for rotating images, i want to add a my own class in to its for some customization the actual code is

```
c.append("<ul class="+b.paginationClass+"></ul>")
```

I want to add/append  a class "**test**" into it  like the following

```
c.append("<ul class="+b.paginationClass+" test"+"></ul>")
```

i put a space because want a space after   paginationClass class, but i got result is

```
<ul class="pagination" test="" >
```

i expect `<ul class="pagination test" >` like this Please help

Comment: did you try `$(element).addClass('class');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c.append("<ul class='"+b.paginationClass+" test'></ul>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic?!

```
c.find('ul.'+b.paginationClass).addClass('test');
```

Comment: Thanks i got answer from here

Answer (score 1):

Create an element the proper way using jQuery. jQuery will try to normalize your string as much as possible, but append is not html().

```
c.append($('<ul></ul>', { 'class': b.paginationClass + ' test' }));
```

Or:

```
c.html(c.html() + '<ul class="' + b.paginationClass + ' test"></ul>');
```